# How do I play video through a projector without seeing the player buttons?

Tags: video, quicktime, projector

This is probably one of those questions with a really easy answer but either I'm not phrasing it right or there isn't a way to do what I'm wanting. At my church, we occasionally play videos from a MacBook Pro or our new 2019 iMac. The video pipes out to the projector just fine, everything works fine. 
The issue is when a video needs to be played or paused 300 people can see the mouse move over the Quicktime player's play/pause button. This seems very amateur hour but for the life of me I can't figure out how to play and pause a video in the booth without the buttons showing up on the projector screen.
I feel like I saw a video on how do do this years ago, but I haven't been able to figure it out.
Can this be done?
Thanks!

Comment: If the controls (play/pause/etc.) are overlaid on the video output, there’s not much you can do. However, there are players that support remote control via app or command line utility so you're not using the control overlay, but a different window altogether or even via a different device like an  iPhone or iPad.  Try: https://www.dvdfab.cn/tips/How-to-control-the-video-playback-with-Virtual-Remote-on-mac.htm (I’ve not used it myseld).  VLC might have this ability as well.

Answer (score 1):

Both Quicktime Player & VLC will show the cursor & transport if you move the mouse, but both will respond to a simple Spacebar tap to play/pause without showing the interface. VLC has an optional || or > indicator.

If you never need to use playlists or run consecutive movies, then stick with Quicktime Player, otherwise, VLC is a much more comprehensive structure.